# Hiding Empty column in html table using jQuery .. doesn't work :\

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script  src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script>


        $('table').each(function(a, tbl) {
            var currentTableRows = $(tbl).attr('rows').length - 1;
            $(tbl).find('th').each(function(i) {
                var remove = 0;
                var currentTable = $(this).parents('table');

                var tds = currentTable.find('tr td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
                tds.each(function(j) { if (this.innerHTML == '') remove++; });

                if (remove == currentTableRows) {
                    $(this).hide();
                    tds.hide();
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table  border="1" >  
        <tr><td colspan="4" > alaa </td></tr>
        <tr><th>Column1</th><th>Column2</th><th>Column3</th><th>Column4</th></tr>
        <tr ><td>1st</td><td>1.1</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="data"><td>2nd</td><td>2.1</td><td></td><td></td></tr>  
        <tr class="data"><td>3rd</td><td>3.1</td><td></td><td>1</td></tr>  
        <tr class="data"><td>4th</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr ><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="data"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>  
    </table>

</body>
```

here is my code ... I thought that the problem from the library, so I tried many libraries such as jQuery 1.4.4 , 1.5.2 and others

Here is the test and it works fine there http://jsfiddle.net/nlovatt/JsLn8/

but in my file .. it doesn't work ..

regards,

Comment: Do you get an error? Can you post a link to your file?

Comment: No .. I don't get any Error .. 

here is the link http://summer.remal.com/provise_alaa/JQ.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons your code isn't working.

1) You're executing the script immediately upon loading of the `HEAD`, at this stage, your table doesn't exist and so it does nothing. To fix this, make sure you execute it on page load instead.

2) When you're comparing the number of blank cells in the column with the number of total rows *in the table*, you're missing the fact that most of your columns don't have the same number of rows as the table (your first row is only one column wide). You need to compare to the number of rows in the actual column, or better yet, just do the reverse thing and check for non-empty columns.

The full code then becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table').each(function(a, tbl) {
        $(tbl).find('th').each(function(i) {
            var remove = true;
            var currentTable = $(this).parents('table');
            var tds = currentTable.find('tr td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
            tds.each(function(j) { if (this.innerHTML != '') remove = false; });
            if (remove) {
                $(this).hide();
                tds.hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This has worked well.  I would note that the currentTableRows variable is unused and unnecessary.  Also, if you have a large number of tables (or nested tables) where you don't want this to apply, you should use a different selector with a class included perhaps and that because of the use of .parents, you need to put that selector in both places where 'table' is used.

Comment: You're right, sorry about leaving that `currentTableRows` in there. As for the use of `.parents`, that's only getting the parent table of the `th` we're looping over, really, this is most likely the same as the `tbl` reference, but I'm not positive on that. If you want to be specific about which table you're applying this to it's all down to the selector in the line `$('table').each(...)`, for example you could change this to `$('table.hiddenColumns').each(...)` where 'hiddenColumns is a CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
    $('#mytable tr th').each(function(i) {
   //select all td in this column
    var tds = $(this).parents('table')
          .find('tr td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
    //check if all the cells in this column are empty
    if(tds.length == tds.filter(':empty').length) { 
        //hide header
        $(this).hide();
        //hide cells
        tds.hide();
    } 
    });
```

for hiding columns in table if all cells in column are empty

Comment: the code has been tested in http://jsfiddle.net/nlovatt/JsLn8/
but in my file .. it doesn't .. why :$

Comment: @TheGhost Probably because of the 1st reason mentioned in my answer - you're executing your code before the tables exist.