# Hide column from html table if there is no data returned from query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an array such:

```
  $values = array();
```

Along with a MySQL query:

```
$query = "SELECT $columns FROM Prices WHERE `key` LIKE '$rows' AND rate LIKE '$rate'";

if($results = $db->query($query)) {
    if($results->num_rows) {
        while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
            $values[] = $row;
        }
        $results->free();
    }
```

I've printed out the table using the following code: (I have removed some table columns)

```
<?php 
if(!count($values)) {
    echo '<p>No results found for your current search. Use the inputs to the left to change the filters.</p>';
 } else {
   ?>
       <table>
           <thead>
               <tr>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>City</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
              foreach ($values as $v) {
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $v->Location; ?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $v->City; ?> </td>
              </tr>
              <?php
              }
              ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
```

I can return data from the MySQL query, and print this to the table. However, sometimes not all the columns need be printed as they have no values. I would like to hide these columns.

i.e table result may be

```
| col 1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4 |
==================================
|       |       |   33  |       |
|       |       |   32  |       |
```

And would become

```
| col 3 |
=========
|   33  |
|   32  |
```

OR

```
| col 1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4 |
==================================
|       |       |       |   65  |
|       |       |       |   25  |
```

would become

```
| col 4 |
=========
|   65  |
|   25  |
```

My question is: How would I hide the empty columns?

Note: table data is populated from user via input form.

I am happy to do this via css, php, or JS

Comment: Possible duplicate (with answer): http://stackoverflow.com/a/4748682/1112669

Comment: So in the first case, you only want the table to contain col 3? And the second, only col4? I think it will help if you provide an example of what you are looking for.

Comment: Do the answers here do anything for you?

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430956/hiding-empty-column-in-html-table-using-jquery-doesnt-work

Comment: With a look at these answers and a bit more thinking, it seems the best option is to add the table headers into the database, return these from the query (i.e. just the columns searched for) the only problem is I'm not sure how to make the top row have "th" tags instead of "tr". Any ideas? - also i had tried to implement @islanddave link except I had no luck

Comment: and yes @bloodyKnuckles

Comment: do it in PHP, iterate over the result to find empty columns, then iterate over it again to display only columns with data.

Comment: I tried using if isset($v->city) { echo ...}; - this worked until i realised i couldnt output the header row unless it was in the foreach loop. in which case sometimes i had multiple header rows depending on what data was returned

Comment: Where you have `$prices` do you mean `$values`? Or are you getting $prices somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the returned object has column names for keys, first loop over the first row values to get columns names and write the TH tags, then loop over each row and write out the values.

```
// mocking up values for example
$values = array( (object) array("col_1" => 72, "col_3" => 44, "col_4" => 16), (object) array("col_1" => 51, "col_3" => 87, "col_4" => 34));

// error message if no results
if(!count($values)) {
    echo '<p>No results found for your current search. Use the inputs to the left to change the filters.</p>';

// display results
} else {
?>
 <table border="1">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <?php foreach ($values[0] as $k => $c) { /* loop first row to get column names */ ?>
            <th> <?php echo $k; ?> </th>
          <?php } ?>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($values as $v) { /* loop rows */ ?>
        <tr>
          <?php foreach ($v as $k => $c) { /* loop columns */ ?>
            <td> <?php echo $c; ?> </td>
          <?php } ?>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

Output:

```
| col_1  | col_3 | col_4 |
==========================
| 72     | 44    | 16    |
| 51     | 87    | 34    |
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a dream. I Also got the javascript version working too. The question is which is a better implementation. Using the php version I have to change my table values in MySQL from small ints to varchars to store the table column names, for the JS version the user has to have javascript enabled/capabilites. whats your opinion?

Comment: So many factors to consider. Questions I expect I'd ask myself: Do other parts of the site require Javascript? Are my end users likely to NOT have JS available? Is it to my advantage to offload this processing to the browser? Which is more maintainable, scalable? ...come immediately to mind. Thanks for the acceptance.

Comment: I did notice one issue with your code, as I had to generate the first row in the database to be the column headers, this was then repeated in the table body. I assume this is because first foreach ($values[0] as $k => $c) is used then foreach ($values as $v). I assume $values need to be run from $values[1] onwards? would this be done by setting ($values[n] as $v) and running a for loop from 1 to n?

Comment: Sure you can start the loop at the second row, BUT...what are the advantages of putting the columns names as the first row in the database? You can get the column names as keys in the query response without doing that. If you want to modify the columns names, such as replace "_" with a space, I prefer to do that in the code.